# Wildfly Scheduled EJB- executes multiple times

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly

I´ve created a test application, which contains an EJB, that should print the current Timestamp every second. Now after deploying the web application on my wildfly, i´m getting around 5 log-messages every second...looks like there are running multiple schedulers, which triggers the output...

Do you have any ideas, how to fix it? If i just annotate the methode with @Schedule, it prints every second the result, but by setting the timer programmatically makes problems:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Scheduler {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Timeout
    public void doStuff() {
        logger.info("Programmatic Scheduler: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void startScheduler() {

        TimerConfig timerConfig = new TimerConfig();
        timerConfig.setPersistent(false);

        ScheduleExpression expression = new ScheduleExpression();
        expression.second("*/1").minute("*").hour("*");
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(expression, timerConfig);
    }
}
```

... and here´s the output- you see, multiple prints per second:

```
    16:26:46,574 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 10) Programmatic Scheduler: 143455120657
    16:26:46,849 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 8) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551206849
    16:26:46,869 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 7) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551206869
    16:26:46,890 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 4) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551206890
    16:26:47,083 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 3) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551207083
    16:26:47,145 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 1) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551207145
    16:26:47,185 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 9) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551207185
    16:26:47,246 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 6) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551207246
    16:26:47,274 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 2) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551207274
    16:26:47,489 INFO  [de.hays.liferay.schedulerprogrammatically.Scheduler] (EJB default - 5) Programmatic Scheduler: 1434551207489
```

Answer (score 2):

I´ve got it- i looked up with the java mission control for the running Timers on the wildfly- and there were more than one Timer.

So i´ve edited my code, to kill all existing timers for the application and then create ONE timer, to make sure, there is really just one Timer:

```
@PostConstruct
public void startScheduler() {

    TimerService timerService = sessionContext.getTimerService();

    logger.info("Current running timers: {}", timerService.getTimers().toString());

    for (Timer t : timerService.getTimers()) {
        t.cancel();
        logger.info("killed the timer service: {}", t);
    }

    TimerConfig timerConfig = new TimerConfig();
    timerConfig.setPersistent(false);

    Timer createdIntervalTimer = sessionContext.getTimerService().createIntervalTimer(0, 5000, timerConfig);
    logger.info("Created new Timer: {}", createdIntervalTimer);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your package imports. `javax.inject.Singleton` would explain the behaviour, being ignored by EJB. `javax.ejb.Singleton` is the one you want.

Comment: Yes i was using the javax.ejb.Singleton